# Is Gsuite API domain-wide delegation service accounts can enable all organization's users gmail push notifications

Tags: push-notification, gmail-api, webhooks, google-directory-api, google-workspace

i have created a service account and gave it a full access thrugh the admin console ([performed the Domain-Wide-Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation))

i successfully retrieving users of the organization and i'm trying to use their Id in order to create a [Watch Request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) so i could receive notifications about each user Gmail Activities.
But I'm receiving the following error: 
**403 - Delegation denied for ____@____.com (impersonated user)**

**NOTE** - I've already impersonate admin user with the service account in case  impersonation is needed